# Inspect element HTML set root file path

Tags: html, filepath

I am working on a static (front end only) website and there are a ton of URLs relative to the root. I "run" the code by simply opening an HTML file on my computer, which takes me to  `file:///C:/foo/bar/website/index.html`. Because of this, the root-relative links don't work, since the root is `file:///` instead of `file:///C:/foo/bar/website/`. I was thinking that **maybe chrome inspect element had a way to set a root directory**?

I can't fix all the paths because I am only supposed to work on a chunk of CSS in a single page, and if I change all the paths and something breaks for some reason, that would be on me (and even if nothing breaks, I would still be out of line).

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use the website correctly with every URL working fine without to touch anything, I would recommend you to run a small PHP or Apache server. It's very light, it doesn't need any installation, no need to open any port, only to download a zip file.
You can download the PHP server at: https://www.php.net/downloads
Then run the exe file with command:
`php -S localhost:8080`
And go to localhost:8080 in your browser. You should have a perfectly working website hosted on your computer.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend listening on *every* network interface for local development by default. It's useful if you need to to test on a different device, but generally you wouldn't want to give everyone on your network access to  your work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

> maybe chrome inspect element had a way to set a root directory?

It doesn't.

---

Install a web server and test your code using that.

You could use the [PHP built-in server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

or [the live server extension for VS code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)

or the [python HTTP module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server#Running_a_simple_local_HTTP_server)

… among others.